# Troublshoot website on BlackBerry browser

Tags: testing, blackberry

I have a client request to have our website support certain BlackBerry devices.  I am running into a fundamental issue when trying to login to the site.  I think it may be a JavaScript function, but I really have no idea how I can test to be sure.

How can I troubleshoot and test my website on a BlackBerry browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the emulators?

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/index.shtml

Comment: I have and trying to get the to work and access the internet has been challenging.  If that is the only option I have I will continue to wrestle with them.